# Changing global variable value in callback function

Tags: node.js

I'm calling function and return data push into an array but array is empty

```
property.forEach(function(proObj){
  var photo=[];
  proObj.photosId.forEach(function(Pid){
    fileUpload.fetchPhotoById(Pid,function(photoObj){
      photo.push(photoObj); //photo obj is added to photo Array
      console.log('source:-'+photoObj); // getting data correctly
    }) 
  })
  proObj.photos=photo;  
  console.log('Photo Array'+photo); // photo has default value means empty array
})
```

Please help me anyone to resolve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: i couldn't understand that explaination any simple solution

Comment: all the functions are async, you can get the result only in callback function ( or use promises or async-await)

Comment: I have used callback but not getting

Comment: Use let photo = [];

Comment: let also not working